# Android http response doesn't work

Tags: java, php, android, xml, httpresponse

Hello I am trying to create an activity, in which the android sends values to the php script, which inserts values to a mysql database and then the response comes in an android textview.
When I run the app and click the button, the dialog box appears saying "creating chatroom.." and when the process finishes the dialog box disappears and I don't get any response in the textview, but I find that the values are successfully inserted in the database. what's wrong with my code?

note:I don't get any errors, and the app doesn't crash, and I added the internet permission in the manifest.

This is the java code:

```
public class SubmitRoomActivity extends Activity {
    String username;
    String ccolor;
    String crname;
    Button b;
    EditText et,pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response2;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    public final static String CHATTER_NAME = "com.gowemto.gowemto.USERNAME";
    public final static String CHATTER_COLOR = "com.gowemto.gowemto.CCOLOR";
    public final static String CHATROOM_NAME = "com.gowemto.gowemto.CRNAME";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_submit_room);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.subroom);  

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logerr2);

             Intent intent = getIntent();
              username = intent.getStringExtra(SelectRoomActivity.CHATTER_NAME);
              ccolor = intent.getStringExtra(SelectRoomActivity.CHATTER_COLOR);
              crname = intent.getStringExtra(SelectRoomActivity.CHATROOM_NAME);
             final TextView welcominguser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_user_2);
             if(ccolor.trim().equals("Black")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Blue")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Red")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Orange")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Green")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Gray")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Brown")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#804000"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Purple")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
             }
             else if(ccolor.trim().equals("Pink")){

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4080"));
             }
             else {

                 welcominguser.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
             }
             welcominguser.setText("Hello, " + username);



        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SubmitRoomActivity.this, "", 
                        "Creating room..", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();                          
                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });
    }

    void login(){
        try{            
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/mychat/createroom"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ccolor",ccolor));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("roomname",crname)); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response2=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response2 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText(response2);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });



        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            tv.setText("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the xml code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" 
        android:background="#EED8FF">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello_user_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
          <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:text="@+string/room_inst_2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/second_colors"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/sec_color_names" />
            <Button 
                   android:id="@+id/subroom"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                   android:text="@string/cont_act"
                style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
                   android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
                    android:onClick="gotoRoom"
               />
              <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:id="@+id/logerr2"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
            </LinearLayout

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the php script:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="chat_db";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$roomname = $_POST['roomname'];
$roomcolor = $_POST['ccolor'];
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO chatrooms VALUES('$username','$roomname','$roomcolor')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_insert) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Room created successfully"; 

?>
```

How can I fix this problem? what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the content on php with:

`$response = file_get_contents("http://10.0.2.2/mychat/createroom");`

And then decode the json values with json_decode($response)

Answer (score 0):

You get no errors because you have this:

```
   }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        tv.setText("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

You catch all Exceptions (so your app doesn't crash), but you don't log the exception so you have no idea what your problem is. Also, you call `tv.setText()` from a background thread. Very bad.

Try adding some logging here.

Comment: but I don't get anything in the text view.

Comment: and what's the background thread? and what's the problem with calling from it? and what can I do for it?

Comment: In the `onClick()` method of your `OnClickListener` you create a new `Thread`. This thread is a background thread, not the Main (UI) thread. You cannot do anything to UI elements (Views, etc.) on any thread other than the Main (UI) thread. This is not allowed because the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe. This is one of the first things you learn when programming on Android.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Did anything happen?

Comment: even when I remove the catch exception method, the app doesn't crash.

Comment: OK. Do you see any errors? Have you stepped through it with a debugger? You are also calling `httpclient.execute()` twice. It looks like you aren't paying much attention :-(

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the post method twice. This could be a problem if you have set some unique constraints
for your table.

```
//Execute HTTP Post Request
response2=httpclient.execute(httppost);
// edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
final String response2 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

A single post request is sufficient for your cause I think. It's confusing to have two variables of same name but different type too. Like response2 is HttpResponse and again another is a String.

If you are using the first execute call then you could get the response string like this:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: okay thanks :) which "response" should I remove from my code? the httpresponse or the string one?

Comment: Try by removing the httpresponse.